# How to increase maximum artifacts size for Gitlab on-premises

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We've installed Gitlab on-premises, however someone else did the installation so I don't know as much about configuring the runners, etc.  A pipeline failed due to the following error:

```
Uploading artifacts...
app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk: found 1 matching files
app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk: found 1 matching files
ERROR: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... too large archive id=13832 responseStatus=413 Request Entity Too Large status=413 Request Entity Too Large token=fCysmH9H
FATAL: Too large
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Where/how do I configure the allowable artifact size?

Answer (score 18):

I was able to solve my problem after finding https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2584.  It suggests increasing maximum artifacts size on the on-prem instance of Gitlab.  Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. Click Admin Area (top of Gitlab on-prem screen)
2. Click Settings

   2. The direct link, assuming the on-prem instance is hosted at gitlab.MYCOMPANY.com is: `https://gitlab.MYCOMPANY.com/admin/application_settings/ci_cd`
3. Expand "Continuous Integration and Deployment"
4. Set the "Maximum artifacts size (MB)"

This assumes your login credentials allow you to see the Admin Area.

Comment: Also change `nginx['client_max_body_size'] = '1024m'` accordingly to fit the highest maximum artifact size allowed.