# Gitlab Self-Hosted: ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... too large archive

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

Some time ago, our Gitlab (self-hosted) instance started to throw errors that the archives are too big:

> ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... too large
> archive  id=something responseStatus=413 Request Entity Too Large
> status=413 token=something FATAL: too large
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

The only resolution ideas we found was to set the max build artifact size (it's under /admin/application_settings). This did not work for us, the error still occurred.

Reference articles:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/infrastructure/-/issues/3813
- https://dzone.com/articles/gitlab-ci-runner-artifacts-size-error-quottoo-larg
- https://www.kevinhooke.com/2018/07/30/gitlab-ci-runner-artifacts-size-error-too-large-archive/
- https://forum.gitlab.com/t/uploading-artifacts-too-large-archive-error-413/4867
- [How to increase maximum artifacts size for Gitlab on-premises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367224/how-to-increase-maximum-artifacts-size-for-gitlab-on-premises)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to set the max build artifact size (under /admin/application_settings) and to increase the Gitlab NGINX `client_max_body_size` property in the configuration file to something higher.

Answer (score 26):

From gitlab official docs:

**The maximum size of the job artifacts can be set at:**

> The value is in MB and the default is 100MB per job.

**To change it at the instance level:**

On the top bar, select `Menu > Admin`.
On the left sidebar, select `Settings > CI/CD`.
Change the value of maximum artifacts size (in MB).
Select Save changes for the changes to take effect.
Group level (this overrides the instance setting):

**To change it at the group level:**

Go to the group’s `Settings > CI/CD > General Pipelines`.
Change the value of maximum artifacts size (in MB).
Select Save changes for the changes to take effect.
Project level (this overrides the instance and group settings):

**To change it at the project level:**

Go to the project’s `Settings > CI/CD > General Pipelines`.
Change the value of maximum artifacts size (in MB).
Select Save changes for the changes to take effect.

Ref: [Maximum artifacts size](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/continuous_integration.html#maximum-artifacts-size)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 413 Request Entity Too Large

Solution: Try cleaning cache of GitLab runner

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case build was too large because of `artifacts:untracked` flag. Setting it to false solved the problem.