# Log the size of the artifacts archive before upload attempt in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an on-prem instance of GitLab and I started seeing the following error in one of the pipelines:

```
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as “archive” to coordinator… 
413 Request Entity Too Large id=1390915 responseStatus=413 Request Entity Too Large status=413
```

Before I go to the admins and request that they increase the limit (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64329087/gitlab-self-hosted-error-uploading-artifacts-as-archive-to-coordinator-to)), **I would like to see what is the size of the compressed artifact** - perhaps I am packing too many things.

I am using:

- gitlab-runner 14.7.0
- windows

**How can I log the size of the package into the output?**

Answer (score 2):

A way to achieve this is by passing the path to the artifact to the `du` command.

- `du` (disc usage) command estimates file_path space usage
- The options `-sh` are (from `man du`):

```
 -s, --summarize
         display only a total for each argument

  -h, --human-readable
         print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

E.g

```
...
script:
...
  - du -hs path/to/artifacts
artifacts:
  paths:
    - path/to/artifacts
```

output:

```
40M     path/to/artifacts
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use `gci` and `measure` to get the size in bytes of a directory, using powershell.

So, in your GitLab job you could use the following method, assuming that `.\dist` is your artifact directory:

```yaml
my_job:
  after_script:
    - powershell -c "gci -Recurse .\dist | Measure-Object -Property Length -sum"
```

You can omit the `powershell -c` and quotes if your runner uses powershell by default.

You'll see an output like:

```
Count    : 1234
Average  :
Sum      : 1234567890  # <--- this is the size in bytes
Minimum  :
Maximum  :
Property : Length
```

If you're using Linux images on a docker executor on Windows, then you can use the method mentioned in the other answer.

Unfortunately, it's not practical to get the **compressed** size of the artifact from your end. In part, because the compression algorithm is determined by the GitLab runner's settings. Additionally, some artifacts, like any under `reports:` are *not* compressed at all. GitLab also generates metadata files for each individual artifact, which will contribute to the overall storage size.

You can *guess* the approximate compressed size by first using `gzip` to compress your artifacts (as GoLang's `compress/gzip` is what is used by the runner) then using the above method. Though, I wouldn't expect compressed size to be significantly smaller unless your artifact data lends itself well to compression, so the uncompressed size should be reasonable for an Admin to use to increase your limits.

Keep in mind, you'll probably want to request a limit with some reasonable overhead in case your artifact size varies in the future.

Comment: Thanks - I think the compression matters a lot. In one of the pipelines, my artifacts folder is over 1900MB but the compressed file is 656 megabytes...
You can probably guess I am after the size of whatever gitlab is failing to upload (why, oh why doesn't the error mention it?). Obviously if I go to admins to increase the limit, they will ask 'to what size' :D